# Problem transferring data from one site to another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shopping-cart

I have a database with products in it, and I also have a shop.php page where all the products are displayed. If I click on a specific product there, I will be redirected to the product.php page and the data displayed as shown:

```
session_start();
require_once "connection.php";

$product_id = $_GET['product_id'] ?? null;


if ($product_id) {
    $sql_product = "SELECT picture, product_name, price, Size FROM product WHERE product_id = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql_product);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $product_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result_product = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($result_product && mysqli_num_rows($result_product) > 0) {
        $row_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_product);

       
        $product_name = $row_product['product_name'];
        $product_price = $row_product['price'];
        $product_picture = $row_product['picture'];
    }
```

Then I want to send it to the cart.php page with an Ajax request when the user clicks on the addtocart button:

```
 document.getElementById("addToCartBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var productName = "<?php echo $product_name; ?>";
    var productPrice = "<?php echo $product_price; ?>";
    var productPicture = "<?php echo $product_picture; ?>";
    var quantity = document.querySelector("select[name='quantity']").value;
    var size = document.getElementById("sizeSelect").value; 

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "cart.php", true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            
            
            console.log(xhr.responseText); 
        }
    };
    
    xhr.send("product_name=" + encodeURIComponent(productName) + "&product_price=" + encodeURIComponent(productPrice) + "&product_picture=" + encodeURIComponent(productPicture) + "&quantity=" + encodeURIComponent(quantity) + "&size=" + encodeURIComponent(size));
});
```

And here is the cart.php, as I try to display the sent products:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if (isset($_GET['remove_item'])) {
    $remove_index = $_GET['remove_item'];
    
    if (array_key_exists($remove_index, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$remove_index]); 
    }
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['index']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    $index = $_POST['index'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    
    if (array_key_exists($index, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['quantity'] = $quantity;
        echo $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['quantity'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['product_price'] . '€'; 
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
    exit; 
}
<tr>
        <td><a href="cart.php?remove_item=<?php echo $index; ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></a></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $item['product_picture']; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: auto;"></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['size']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['product_price']; ?>€</td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="quantity_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>" min="1" onchange="updateQuantity(<?php echo $index; ?>, this.value)">
        </td>
        <td id="total_<?php echo $index; ?>"><?php echo $item['quantity'] * $item['product_price']; ?>€</td>
    </tr>
```

I don't know what could be the cause of the problem. I think that the product.php page does not send the individual products for some reason.

Comment: *"I don't know what could be the cause of the problem."* - What problem?  Can you clarify what isn't working as expected?  If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  Those can help you narrow down where specifically the problem happens.

Comment: the product data is not sent to the cart.php page

Comment: In your browser's development tools, check the Network tab.  When the AJAX request is made, does the request on that tab contain the data you expect?  When you examine the client-side JavaScript code which makes that request, does the PHP code above generate the JavaScript code you expect?

Comment: `the product data is not sent to the cart.php page`...how exactly have you determined this? As David says, please give details of what debugging you've done.

Comment: What data you are trying to send there, makes rather little sense to begin with. Why are you sending data from the client to the server, that is already known on the server side? The only thing you should be sending, is the product (or record) id, and the quantity. If you need the product name or picture on any subsequent pages - then you go and read them from the database, using the ID. [...]

Comment: [...] And when you have to calculate the price - then you do that with the quantity submitted from the from, and the price _read from the database_. If you use a price that I am passing to you from the frontend for the calculation - then I will simply change that price value of 5 (dollars) that you _wanted_ the item to cost, to -5000 - and now _you owe me_ quantity times 5000 dollars ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This might be important for you to read up - [GET & POST Request Training PHP](https://zetcode.com/php/getpostrequest/)
Also : [$_POST - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Now coming back to your code on the AJAX Xml HTTP Request (My suggestion use a library like JQuery to make it less verbose.)
Your sending a HTTP POST Request on Client-side Javascript, so on server-side PHP needed to change your PHP code like this :

```
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'] ?? null;
```

Hope this helps.